# What attack modes does a VPN secure against over https?

Tags: tls, vpn

Suppose all my sensitive traffic is handled over a https connection. Further assume, I've no interest in hiding which sites I visit just want to hide the sensitive contents. i.e. If an adversary knew the fact that I did a dns lookup for foobar.com that doesn't affect me.

Now is there any special advantage to using a VPN?

I mean there's a distinction between anonymity vs security right? If I want anonymity I might use something like tor.

If I want to access geo-restricted content (say) then I might see why I would use a VPN that makes my traffic seem to originate for a US IP even if I am located in (say) Saudi Arabia.

Or if I want to access legacy software that only works over the office intranet and it's rather simple to make it seem like my remote laptop is virtually within  the office intranet than to go about modifying all legacy software individually.

But other than these use cases is there any fundamental benefit to using a VPN over just https?

Answer (score 3):

If all you do is surfing the web and all the surfing you do is already protected with https and you only care about encrypting the traffic but don't care that somebody might see which sites you visit and when and if you can be sure that your https is not intercepted by some local antivirus, local malware/adware or some enterprise firewall or you don't care, then it is enough to use https.

If any of these conditions are not met a VPN might make sense depending on what you do. And note that a VPN is no replacement for https: https provides end to end protection while VPN offers no protection after the traffic leaves the VPN endpoint which is usually not the endpoint of the connection.

Comment: Thanks Steffen! I agree. But one quibble: If a local malware is capable of intercepting https traffic *before* it gets encrypted then neither is a VPN going to save me right? i.e. If the local machine is compromised then all bets are off, right? https / VPN are both rendered ineffective. Correct?

Comment: @curious_cat: that's correct. If the local machine is compromised the attacker might even use a browser extension/inject to grab the data before encryption.

Comment: A VPN is at best an additional attack surface and at worst a MITM scam, so you may even be better off not using it.

Comment: @Fax: Your comment is at best a limited view of VPN and at worst trolling, so one is better off ignoring it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I mean in the exact circumstance where HTTPS is sufficient, not in general (obviously). Or are you suggesting there's no way VPN could possibly reduce security?

Comment: @Fax: *"I mean in the exact circumstance where HTTPS is sufficient, not in general (obviously)"* - I've only seen what you've written and not what you've meant. Apart from that VPN can provide protection against the ISP (or hotspot or whoever is proding internet access) sniffing the meta data to track which sites where visited. Of course, a VPN can also do such sniffing itself so the question is whom to trust more - the ISP or the VPN provider.